# embedding Bokeh server as a library: standalone vs. Tornado and Object Oriented Design

Tags: python, tornado, bokeh

I refer to the [Bokeh's Documentation](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#embedding-bokeh-server-as-a-library) which describes how to embedding Bokeh server as a library. There are several example python there, specifically one for "[standalone](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/0.12.4/examples/howto/server_embed/standalone_embed.py)" and one for "[Tornado](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/0.12.4/examples/howto/server_embed/tornado_embed.py)", yet both use Tornado.
My questions are:

1. What's the conceptual difference if both use Tornado? Why is it called standalone? (I don't know Tornado very well).
2. Can I use a class object-oriented design for coding the GUI rather than a function with global variables, like in the given examples (see `modify_doc` method in both examples and inner methods which refer to variables in outer scope).

Answer (score 2):

1. Like most other Web servers, Bokeh's built-in `Bokeh.server.server.Server` needs an event loop to run on. In the first, "standalone" example, it's running (or "piggybacking" as the docs say) on top of Tornado's `IOLoop`, but the actual application logic is handled by Bokeh's internal `Application` object. (I believe it might be possible to use some other event loop, like the one from Python 3's [`asyncio`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html), but I haven't tested it.) The second example, however, is using [Tornado's Web framework](http://tornado.readthedocs.io/en/stable/webframework.html) to route the requests instead.
2. The example function is not using global variables -- it (or rather the internal callback function) is simply taking advantage of Python's closure mechanism so it can return a callback function to the Bokeh's `FunctionHandler`. I am not that familiar with Bokeh, but apparently there is a number of different ways you can modify the document -- `FunctionHandler`, `CodeHandler`, `ScriptHandler`, `NotebookHandler` etc. In Python, a class is an executable like any other function, so I can easily see passing one to `FunctionHandler` (which should really be called `CallableHandler`).